# why doesn't echo test &>>file work on OS X

Tags: macos, bash, unix, redirect

I have some scripts that I made on an ubuntu box, but these won't work on my OS X.

```
echo test &>>file
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

The idea is that I want to take both stdout and stderr and put into a file.

Comment: `&>>` appears in Bash version 4. With Bash<4 (which is the one by default on OSX) you must use `>>file 2>&1`

Comment: What bash version do you use? I have bash 4.3.30 and I don't get this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The redirection operator `&>>` appears in Bash version 4.

With Bash 3.x (which is the one shipped by default on OSX) you must use *the equivalent form*:

```
>>file 2>&1
```

Comment: If you really need this working in your MacOSX, I strongly suggest you install brew and then download bash - you will need xCode latest version -